# 3 axis accelerometer

Tags: kinematics, acceleration

I want to use the above sensor ( triaxle accelerometer) as to find the acceleration of the legs calf, when this is attached to our leg. This device gives me acceleration in x,y,z direction. I am confused about what would be my total acceleration in the forward direction. as the leg moves forward and backward, the acceleration would be mainly in +xy, -xy plane as z plane is parallel to the ground.

Comment: You need to make your question more clear. For instance, you haven't defined what you mean by the "x,y,z directions". If the accelerometer is attached to a leg, then the orientation of the local x,y,z coordinate system of the accelerometer will rotate with the natural movement of the leg. But then later you speak of the z-plane being parallel to the ground, which suggests that you are not speaking of the accelerometer's local coordinate system. Very confusing question.

Comment: Hi Samuel, basically my project is human gait analysis for which I am using accelerometer to find the acceleration at different points of legs, such as thigh, calf and hip. When attaching this accelerometer to the legs, X axis points forward, Y axis points downwards and Z axis points out of the accelerometer.